# Laravel 4: Config get returns array or null

Tags: php, paypal, laravel, laravel-4, facade

I have already published the config files inside `app/config/packages/lightshire/laravel/` using `php artisan config:publish`. I'm trying to access this

```
$client_id  = Config::get('lightshire/laravel-paypal::client_id');
```

and all it returns is `array(0) { }`

**My Service Provider**

```
<?php
namespace Lightshire\Paypal;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider as IlluminateServiceProvider;

class PaypalServiceProvider extends IlluminateServiceProvider
{
    protected $defer = false;

    public function boot()
    {
        $this->package("lightshire/laravel-paypal");
        include app_path()."/routes.php";
    }

    public function register()
    {
        $this->app["paypal"] = $this->app->share(function($app)
        {

            return new Paypal;
        });
    }
    public function provides()
    {
        return array('paypal');
    }
}
```

**My Paypal.php**

```
<?php
    namespace Lightshire\Paypal;

    require base_path()."/vendor/autoload.php";


    use App;
    use Config;


    class Paypal
    {
        private $creds = null;
        private $token = null;

        public function __construct()
        {
            // // $data = Paypal::launch();
            // $this->creds = $data["creds"];
            // $this->token = $data["token"];

        }



        public static function getTokenCreds()
        {



            $client_id  = Config::get('lightshire/laravel-paypal::client_id');
            $secret     = Config::get('laravel-paypal:secret');
            $mode       = Config::get('laravel-paypal:mode');
            $endPoint   = Config::get('laravel-paypal:endpoint');
;
            $headers    = array(
                    // 'Authorization' => 'Basic '.$encodedID,
                    'Accept'            =>  'application/json',
                    'Accept-Language'   => 'en_US'
                ); 

            $params     = array(
                    'grant_type'    => 'client_credentials'
                ); 

            $url        = "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token";

            dd($client_id);

            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $client_id.":".$secret);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);

            $response = curl_exec($ch);

            curl_close($ch);

            return $response;
        }
    }
```

Any idea why?

Comment: Have you solved your problem? I've the same one.

Answer (score 5):

Try this in the register method on your service provider (you may need to edit the location of the config):

```
$this->app['config']->package('lightshire/laravel-paypal', __DIR__.'/../../config');
```

The second argument is the location of your config (to be published)

You should then be able to access your configuration with:

```
Config::get('laravel-paypal::client_id');
```

Comment: The second argument in 4.2 is the namespace, not path.

Comment: In 4.2 the 3rd parameter is the path